# Make view always fill the swift playground timeline?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Alright, new to playgrounds here but I have a simple question as thus far Ive just been adding a view to my Swift playground with arbitrary numbers like this -

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 600) //view size
let view = SKView(frame: frame)
```

and the view is always skewed to one side of the timeline and/or doesn't fit:

[image]

How can you get the width and height of the timeline in order to scale your view to it?

Answer (score 0):

By default uiView size is fit to screen, you need to change your default device size from then right panel.

Comment: what do you mean?